# mkfs.xfs contains a mounted filesystem

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems

Wanted to reduce a filesystem space.
Did a lvreduce on it. lvreduce successfully ran.
`sudo lvreduce -L 40G /dev/mapper/tmp`
when i am trying to do mkfs.xfs force it is not allowing me saying

`mkfs.xfs: /dev/tmp contains a mounted filesystem`

`sudo lvmdiskscan` shows the correct space after lvreduce. But when i mount it back it is not showing correct space

Can anyone please help here ? Let me know if you need more details
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm seeing this error as well, but for a different reason. I'd like to see some action on this question.

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue and I found this:

https://discuss.pivotal.io/hc/en-us/articles/201816273-xfs-repair-failed-with-error-message-dev-sdb-contains-a-mounted-filesystem-

Basically, comment out the mount in your `fstab` and then reboot. Then perform your format or repair. Re-mount as needed, either manually or in your `fstab`.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. The way I solved it was

1. In the console enter tu super user `su -l`
2. `fdisk -l` to list the devices table
3. `fdisk /dev/device-name`
4. p to print the partition table of the device
5. d to delete partitions
6. n to create a new partition
   if you don't know how to use it you can press `m` to launch help
7. t to assign the tipe of partition, I usually use linux ext4
8. w to write the new partition table in the device
   Is very important to press `w`

Then you can use mkfs

1. `mkfs.fat -F32 /dev/sbc1` you have to change sdc1 with the partition you want to format the -F32 is used in order to assign fat32 file system.

   2.`exit` to standar user

Answer (score 1):

First unmount with *umount device* then perform the size reduction

Answer (score 0):

Unmount the selected partition in Disk Utility with the stop icon button.